# Tool to daemonize Java program

Tags: windows, gratis, java

I search a free program that is able to daemonize Java programs, mainly for Windows where it needs to run them as services. Support for Linux would be ok, but is not a prerequisite.
The program needs to support 32 and 64 bit architectures and must be free in the sense of no licensing fees. In addition to this it needs to be free for commercial use.

I already know `Apache Commons Daemon` and `WinRun4J` and some attempts by volunteers to compile `Tanuki`, but all of these are either rather old or haven't been updated in a while.

I like the idea of having a simple exe under whos name the program is being run and because of this don't "like" approaches where wrappers simply spawn the java.exe because this makes it difficult to nuke the process if it ever stops working. In the past I gave `YAJSW` a try but couldn't become accustomed to it.